# aws-api-gateway-client API POST method issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk-nodejs

We use `aws-api-gateway-client` to exeucte all aws-rest API. Below code was working fine till we upgrade our server from `window 2008` to `window 2016`.

On new Window Server 2016 below code works perfectly fine for `GET / Delete` methods but for `POST` method is not working. Please see the response error below.

Window 2016 package version - `aws-api-gateway-client@0.3.3`

Window 2008 Ppackage version - `aws-api-gateway-client@0.2.16`

Anyone has seen a similar issue after the upgrade?

```
/* ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
API NAME : Invoke AWS REST API using node js
Library Used: aws-api-gateway-client
Date : 1/18/2019
Owner: #######
******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************** */

var apigClientFactory = require('aws-api-gateway-client').default;
process.argv.splice(0, 2)
let command = JSON.parse(process.argv.join(" ").split('\\').join('') || '{}');

var output = {};
process.on("exit", function() {
    printOutput();
});

var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
    invokeUrl: command.endpoint, // REQUIRED
    accessKey: command.access_key, // REQUIRED
    secretKey: command.secret_key, // REQUIRED
    region: command.region, // REQUIRED: The region where the AapiKeyloyed.
    retries: 4,
    retryCondition: (err) => { // OPTIONAL: Callback to further control if request should be retried.  Uses axon-retry plugin.
        return err.response && err.response.status === 500;
    }
});

var pathParams = command.pathParams;
var pathTemplate = command.pathTemplate; // '/api/v1/sites'
var method = command.method; // 'POST';
var additionalParams = command.additionalParams; //queryParams & Headers if any

var body = command.body;

apigClient.invokeApi(pathParams, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams, body)
    .then(function(result) {
        var statuscode = result.status;
        var statustext = result.statusText;
        var job_id = result.headers['location'];
        var responseBody = result.data;
        output.statuscode = statuscode,
            output.statustext = statustext,
            output.job_id = job_id,
            output.responseBody = responseBody;
        //output.result = result;

    }).catch(function(error) {
        if (error.response != undefined) {
            var statuscode = error.response.status;
            var statustext = error.response.statusText;
            var responseBody = error.response.data;
            output.statuscode = statuscode,
                output.statustext = statustext,
                output.responseBody = responseBody;
            //output.response = error;
        } else {
            var statuscode = error.code;
            var statustext = error.errno;
            output.statuscode = statuscode;
            output.statustext = statustext;
            //output.error = error;
        }
    });


function printOutput() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
}
```

Response Error

```
{"statuscode":403,"statustext":"Forbidden","responseBody":{"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'POST\n<>\n"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed `aws-api-gateway-client@0.3.3` and installed a working version of NPM module

```
>npm install aws-api-gateway-client@0.2.16
```